# access router web interface from outside (have ssh access to machine inside)

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, router, remote-access

I'm trying to access my router web interface remotely, but I don't have access to the router for another few months (traveling).

internally, my ubuntu server's IP is [192.168.1.111].  My router IP is [192.168.1.1]

let's say the domain name *example.com* forwards to my router (WAN IP).  I currently have port 80 fwd'ed to 192.168.1.111.  (I also have port 22 fwd'ed).

Can I set SSH up on my Ubuntu server (or something else) that will allow me to fwd *back* to the router (192.168.1.1)?

Basically I want to put in "example.com" on my laptop (in another country) and see my router's web interface.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

You must allow SSH port forwarding on your router, so that external hosts can SSH to a host inside your network. You must also be careful to secure the machine inside your network, and use a strong password.

1. Determine the IP address of your broadband connection. I use DynDNS.org on my router, so that I just need to remember a hostname, not an IP. Most broadband connections use DHCP, so the IP address will change. DynDNS will update your hostname to point to the new IP address.
2. Connect to your router using SSH tunneling, like this:

   externalhost % ssh -L 10080:192.168.1.1:80 yourhostname.dyndns.org

This will create an SSH connection from your local host to yourhostname.dyndns.org (which is a host inside your network). The '-L' will create a SSH tunnel from port 10080 to the router at 192.168.1.1 port 80.

3. Then with your browser, connect to http://localhost:10080/

Comment: This works well with non SSL web interface. With SSL enabled web it does not seems to work.

Comment: I use SSH port forwarding to connect to SSL servers all the time (I did it this morning, in fact). Note that if SSL is enabled you will need to change the ports above to match the SSL ports on your device (probably port 443, but some vendors chose another port).

Comment: Thanks, It later worked for me too. I was just making typo error. Thanks anyways for getting back on this.